# Why does my spark application fail in cluster mode but successful in client mode?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

I am trying to run below pyspark program which will copy the files from a HDFS cluster.

```
import pyspark
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

def read_file(spark):
    try:
        csv_data = spark.read.csv('hdfs://hostname:port/user/devuser/example.csv')
        csv_data.write.format('csv').save('/tmp/data')
        print('count of csv_data: {}'.format(csv_data.count()))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return False
    return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = SparkSession.builder.master('yarn').config('spark.app.name','dummy_App').config('spark.executor.memory','2g').config('spark.executor.cores','2').config('spark.yarn.keytab','/home/devuser/devuser.keytab').config('spark.yarn.principal','devuser@NAME.COM').config('spark.executor.instances','2').config('hadoop.security.authentication','kerberos').config('spark.yarn.access.hadoopFileSystems','hdfs://hostname:port').getOrCreate()
    if read_file(spark):
        print('Read the file successfully..')
    else:
        print('Reading failed..')
```

If I run the above code using `spark-submit` with deploy mode as client, the job runs fine and I can see the output in the dir `/tmp/data`

```
spark-submit --master yarn --num-executors 1 --deploy-mode client --executor-memory 1G --executor-cores 1 --driver-memory 1G --files /home/hdfstest/conn_props/core-site_fs.xml,/home/hdfstest/conn_props/hdfs-site_fs.xml check_con.py
```

But if I run the same code with `--deploy-mode cluster`,

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --num-executors 1 --executor-memory 1G --executor-cores 1 --driver-memory 1G --files /home/hdfstest/conn_props/core-site_fs.xml,/home/hdfstest/conn_props/hdfs-site_fs.xml check_con.py
```

The job fails with kerberos exception as below:

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Client cannot authenticate via:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.selectSaslClient(SaslRpcClient.java:173)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.saslConnect(SaslRpcClient.java:390)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupSaslConnection(Client.java:615)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2300(Client.java:411)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:801)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:797)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:797)
        ... 55 more
```

The code contains the keytab information of the cluster where I am reading the file from. But I don't understand why it fails in cluster mode but runs in client mode.

Should I make any config changes in the code to run it on cluster mode ? Could anyone let me how can I fix this problem ?

Edit 1: I tried to pass the keytab and principle details from spark-submit instead of hard coding them inside the program as below:

```
def read_file(spark):
    try:
        csv_data = spark.read.csv('hdfs://hostname:port/user/devuser/example.csv')
        csv_data.write.format('csv').save('/tmp/data')
        print('count of csv_data: {}'.format(csv_data.count()))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return False
    return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = SparkSession.builder.master('yarn').config('spark.app.name','dummy_App').config('spark.executor.memory','2g').config('spark.executor.cores','2').config('spark.executor.instances','2').config('hadoop.security.authentication','kerberos').config('spark.yarn.access.hadoopFileSystems','hdfs://hostname:port').getOrCreate()
    if read_file(spark):
        print('Read the file successfully..')
    else:
        print('Reading failed..')
```

Spark-submit:

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --name checkCon --num-executors 1 --executor-memory 1G --executor-cores 1 --driver-memory 1G --files /home/devuser/conn_props/core-site_fs.xml,/home/devuser/conn_props/hdfs-site_fs.xml --principal devuser@NAME.COM --keytab /home/devuser/devuser.keytab check_con.py
```

Exception:

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, executor name, executor 2): java.io.IOException: DestHost:destPort <port given in the csv_data statement> , LocalHost:localPort <localport name>. Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Client cannot authenticate via:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]
```

Comment: can you remove all these lines ```.config('spark.executor.memory','2g')
.config('spark.executor.cores','2')
.config('spark.executor.instances','2')
.config('hadoop.security.authentication','kerberos')
.config('spark.yarn.access.hadoopFileSystems','hdfs://hostname:port')
``` & try

Comment: also change this ```spark.read.csv('hdfs://hostname:port/user/devuser/example.csv')``` with ```spark.read.csv('/user/devuser/example.csv')```

Comment: use this spark-submit command - ```spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --name checkCon --num-executors 1 --executor-memory 1G --executor-cores 1 --driver-memory 1g -–conf spark.yarn.keytab=/home/devuser/devuser.keytab -–conf spark.yarn.principal=devuser@NAME.COM check_con.py``` & let me know if its not working

Comment: Removed all the configs, passed the keytab & principal from spark-submit. But the job is still failing with same exception.

Comment: is keytab & principal valid ?

Comment: Yes they are, I copied the keytab from the cluster where my file is and the principal is also the same of that cluster's keytab. Or should I just invoke the keytab present in that cluster instead of copying ?

Comment: You don't seem to be aware that **some Spark properties (like Kerberos auth) are consumed by the `Client` component, on the client machine, before the `Driver` is started**. In the case of `yarn-client` execution, the Driver runs in the same JVM as the Client, and I guess the Driver is actually using a local Kerberos TGT to create Hadoop delegation tokens for the Executors. But in `yarn-cluster`, boom.

Comment: TL;DR never set up configuration by Python/Scala code unless you **know** (e.g. by reviewing source code in GitHub) that it is safe to do so. Always set it by conf files or on the command line.

Comment: And **Hadoop properties must be passed either via standard Hadoop conf files, or via Spark props with `spark.hadoop.` prefix** e.g. `spark-submit --conf spark.hadoop.hadoop.security.authentication=KERBEROS`

Answer (score 0):

Because of this `.config('spark.yarn.keytab','/home/devuser/devuser.keytab')` conf.
In `client` mode your job will be running in local & given path is available so Job completed successfully.

Where as in `cluster` mode `/home/devuser/devuser.keytab` not available or accessible in data nodes & driver so it is failing.

```
SparkSession\
.builder\
.master('yarn')\
.config('spark.app.name','dummy_App')\
.config('spark.executor.memory','2g')\
.config('spark.executor.cores','2')\
.config('spark.yarn.keytab','/home/devuser/devuser.keytab')\ # This line is causing problem
.config('spark.yarn.principal','devuser@NAME.COM')\
.config('spark.executor.instances','2')\
.config('hadoop.security.authentication','kerberos')\
.config('spark.yarn.access.hadoopFileSystems','hdfs://hostname:port')\
.getOrCreate()
```

**Don't hardcode** `spark.yarn.keytab` & `spark.yarn.principal` configs.
Pass these configs as part of `spark-submit` command.

```
spark-submit --class ${APP_MAIN_CLASS} \
    --master yarn \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --name ${APP_INSTANCE} \
    --files ${APP_BASE_DIR}/conf/${ENV_NAME}/env.conf,${APP_BASE_DIR}/conf/example-application.conf \
    -–conf spark.yarn.keytab=path_to_keytab \
    -–conf spark.yarn.principal=principal@REALM.COM \
    --jars ${JARS} \
    [...]
```

Comment: It still didn't work. I removed the keytab details from the code and submitted like this
`spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --name checkCon --num-executors 1 --executor-memory 1G --executor-cores 1 --driver-memory 1G --files /path/core-site_fs.xml,/path/hdfs-site_fs.xml --principal devuser@NAME.COM --keytab /home/devuser/devuser.keytab check_con.py` but still find the same exception. I have update the same details in the question.

Comment: sorry, I have changed configs - ```-–conf spark.yarn.keytab=path_to_keytab ``` and ```-–conf spark.yarn.principal=principal@REALM.COM ``` try add these & test one more time.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK,
the below approach will solve your problem,

`KERBEROS_KEYTAB_PATH=/home/devuser/devuser.keytab` and `KERBEROS_PRINCIPAL=devuser@NAME.COM` .

**Approach 1: with kinit command**

**step 1: kinit and proceed with spark-submit**

```
kinit -kt ${KERBEROS_KEYTAB_PATH} ${KERBEROS_PRINCIPAL}
```

**step 2: Run `klist` and verify Kerberization is correctly working for the logged in devuser.**

```
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_XXXXXXXXX_XXXXXX
Default principal: devuser@NAME.COM

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
07/30/2020 15:52:28  07/31/2020 01:52:28  krbtgt/NAME.COM@NAME.COM
        renew until 08/06/2020 15:52:28
```

**step 3: replace the spark code with spark session**

```
sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).appName("TEST1").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
```

**step 4:  Run spark-submit as below.**

```
 $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --class com.test.load.Data \
     --master yarn \
     --deploy-mode cluster \
     --driver-memory 2g \
     --executor-memory 2g \
     --executor-cores 2 --num-executors 2 \
     --conf "spark.driver.cores=2" \
     --name "TEST1" \
     --principal ${KERBEROS_PRINCIPAL} \
     --keytab ${KERBEROS_KEYTAB_PATH} \
     --conf spark.files=$SPARK_HOME/conf/hive-site.xml \
     /home/devuser/sparkproject/Test-jar-1.0.jar 2> /home/devuser/logs/test1.log
```